# How to type 《 》and 〈〉efficiently on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, characters, typing

How to type [`《`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E3%80%8A) `》`and [`〈`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E3%80%88) `〉`efficiently (such as with a simple key combination) on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1: using Emacs

If you have an Emacs window open almost all the time like I do, you can use Emacs to do it, on macOS or other OSs.  Specifically, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then start typing the character's name, namely, "`LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET`".  As you finish typing more and more letters, type `Tab` to prompt a list of matching characters, until it auto-completes it to the unique one.

### Solution 2: using Chinese input method

These characters are CJK book quotation marks.  Many Chinese input methods map `<` to `〈` and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`<` to <kbd>《</kbd>, respectively.  So, if you install a Chinese input method, switch to Chinese mode, and type `<` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`<`, you will get `〈` and  <kbd>《</kbd>.  To type the normal English keyboard `<`, just switch the input method back to English.

Answer (score 39):

For « and »

```
OPTION + \
OPTION + SHIFT + \
```

For ‹ and ›

```
OPTION + SHIFT + 3
OPTION + SHIFT + 4
```

Comment: The guillemet characters are NOT the same as the angle brackets, which are what the original post asked for.

Comment: @qazwsx《 》and «» is indeed different symbol. « is Guillemet symbol while 《 is used in Japanese/Chinese symbol.

I don't know the built-in shortcut for 《. But for Guillemet, you can see the shortcuts in this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet.

Comment: Not the answer to the question on the page, but it is the answer I was looking for and that Google brought me to. So no upvote, but at least accept some kudos 

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing from the year 2021, using macOS 11.1 on an American English keyboard.

| name | character | keypress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| left single guillemet | ‹ | <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> |
| right single guillemet | › | <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> |
| left double guillemet | « | <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> |
| right double guillemet | » | <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> |

This is the same content as a [2018 answer](https://superuser.com/a/1303574/46202), with better markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the Telegram Mac desktop client (possibly, but not verified) you can type two <s  and it will substitute the left Guillemet (and like«wise for two >s, the right Guillemet).   I found this by accident, not being able to get them in otherwise, and was going to use << but I to the proper mark, the left Guillemet, «

That's a lot simpler than doing it here on FF where I had to use the "Symbols and Emoji" option under edit, and find them under the "Parentheses"  option.  Or do and HTML edit if the application allows and use e.g., *&laquo;*. Find a chart for "HTML Entities".

Edit, (2021.09.03 19.41h PDT [GMT -7]):
This no longer appears to be the case. Two < will just give you << and not «.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Import a file like this to [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html):

```
ldab,《
rdab, 》
lab,〈
rab, 〉
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, as of January, 24, 2024. I had to press ALT + SHIFT + V or B. Hope this helps

Comment: ALT key, on Mac OS X, are you sure?